# Change background color without storyboard and viewController in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift3, xcode8.2

I took the one month iOS course and found that the content was a bit outdated because of the changes in Xcode. In lesson 4, the teacher taught us to change the background color in appDelegate.swift by first deleting the storyboard and viewController as well as eliminating the "main" tab in Info.plist. And then he typed in codes in appDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
```

[But the syntax is little bit different in Xcode8.2.1, so i modified it to the code as below. But it doesn't work either.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajBan.png)

[Then i found that there were updated codes on Github for this course.
Unfortunately, it did't work either( but I know it's because it did not define "StaffPicksViewController").](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arOTZ.png) 
So what should i do to change the background color without storyboard and viewController?

Comment: `self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
 self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta`,  mainScreen is changed to main, color Word(Considered needless)  is removed from the UIColor properties eg gray, black, and magenta in your case.

Comment: Yeah, tried exactly what you suggested before.  
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()  But then i get NSexception: Thread1: SIGABRT at runtime...Do you have any other better solutions? Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: Which line did you get the exception?

Comment: class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

Answer (score 0):

I received a great answer from G+:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I just forgot to init a rootViewController...